# Get error when trying to register new user or log in

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

For some reason whenever I make a request to the routes to create a new user I get "This email account is already in use" although the user is created, and when I try to log in I get "The login information was incorrect". I console logged the req.body when logging in and I get the object logged and it seems okay.

My AuthenticationController.js

```
const {User} = require('../models')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const config = require('../config/config')

function jwtSignUser (user) {
  const ONE_WEEK = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
  return jwt.sign(user, config.authentication.jwtSecret, {
    expiresIn: ONE_WEEK
  })
}

module.exports = {
  async register (req, res) {
    try {
      const user = await User.create(req.body)
      const userJson = user.toJSON()
      res.send({
        user: userJson,
        token: jwtSignUser(userJson)
      })
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).send('This email account is already in use.')
    }
  },
  async login (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    try {
      const {email, password} = req.body
      const user = await User.findOne({
        where: {
          email: email
        }
      })

      if (!user) {
        return res.status(403).send({
          error: 'The login information was incorrect'
        })
      }

      const isPasswordValid = await user.comparePassword(password)
      if (!isPasswordValid) {
        return res.status(403).send({
          error: 'The login information was incorrect'
        })
      }

      const userJson = user.toJSON()
      res.send({
        user: userJson,
        token: jwtSignUser(userJson)
      })
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send({
        error: 'An error has occured trying to log in'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

console.log(user) gives me the following:

```
User {
  dataValues:
   { id: 41,
     username: 'testing',
     email: 'testing@gmail.com',
     password:
      '$2a$08$J6/psKuCltiCpCll2rjz4OaCylud0zq/wKnjKK8Udmm.bFU3c2Tt6',
     firstName: 'test',
     lastName: 'ing',
     createdAt: 2019-02-26T15:47:09.133Z,
     updatedAt: 2019-02-26T15:47:09.133Z },
  _previousDataValues:
   { id: 41,
     username: 'testing',
     email: 'testing@gmail.com',
     password:
      '$2a$08$J6/psKuCltiCpCll2rjz4OaCylud0zq/wKnjKK8Udmm.bFU3c2Tt6',
     firstName: 'test',
     lastName: 'ing',
     createdAt: 2019-02-26T15:47:09.133Z,
     updatedAt: 2019-02-26T15:47:09.133Z },
  _changed: {},
  _modelOptions:
   { timestamps: true,
     validate: {},
     freezeTableName: false,
     underscored: false,
     underscoredAll: false,
     paranoid: false,
     rejectOnEmpty: false,
     whereCollection: { email: 'testing@gmail.com' },
     schema: null,
     schemaDelimiter: '',
     defaultScope: {},
     scopes: [],
     indexes: [],
     name: { plural: 'Users', singular: 'User' },
     omitNull: false,
     hooks:
      { beforeCreate: [Array],
        beforeUpdate: [Array],
        beforeSave: [Array] },
     sequelize:
      Sequelize {
        options: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        dialect: [SqliteDialect],
        queryInterface: [QueryInterface],
        models: [Object],
        modelManager: [ModelManager],
        connectionManager: [ConnectionManager],
        importCache: [Object],
        test: [Object] },
     uniqueKeys: { Users_email_unique: [Object] } },
  _options:
   { isNewRecord: false,
     _schema: null,
     _schemaDelimiter: '',
     raw: true,
     attributes:
      [ 'id',
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
        'createdAt',
        'updatedAt' ] },
  __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
  isNewRecord: false }
```

console.log(req.body) gives me this:

```
{ email: 'testing@gmail.com',
  password: 'testing99',
  username: 'testing',
  firstName: 'test',
  lastName: 'ing' }
```

They have the same information but it gives me an error anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `mongoose`, according to the documentation https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne `findOne` is returning `Query` object, so validation may fail.
Check with debugger or even simple `console.log` to see what's inside of the `user` variable in login function.

So if user does not exist, you are getting `Query` object which is not empty, because `mongoose` filled this object with some functions.

You can try to use `lean()`, checkout this article http://www.tothenew.com/blog/high-performance-find-query-using-lean-in-mongoose-2/

Comment: I am actually using Sequelize

Comment: Then try to extract `email` from `dataValues`, or even create some kind of repository which will have transformer which will extract those data values.

Answer (score 0):

We have 2 solution here:

1. Using raw: true

   const user = await User.findOne({
       where: {
         email: email
       },
       raw: true
   })
2. Using plain: true

   user = user.get({
       plain: true
   });